# Difference between DECIMAL and NUMERIC datatype in PSQL

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, sqldatatypes

what is the use of `decimal` and `numeric` datatype in postgreSQL. As per the reference the following is the explanation given to these datatypes.

```
Decimal,numeric --> It is a user specified precision, exact and range up to 131072 digits before the decimal point and up to 16383 digits after the decimal point.
```

The above statement shows the description of `decimal` and `numeric` datatype. But, still I didn't understand what is the
    exact use of these data type and where it is used instead of other datatypes.

Answer with example is much appreciated...

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/121196/1822

Comment: I created a table with `DECIMAL` columns, and Pg12 converted them to `NUMERIC`.

Answer (score 151):

[Right from the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

> The types `decimal` and `numeric` are equivalent. Both types are part of the SQL standard.

As for the "why do I need to use it", this is also explained in the manual:

> The type numeric can store numbers with a very large number of digits and **perform calculations exactly**

(Emphasis mine).

If you need numbers with decimals, use `decimal` (or `numeric`) if you need numbers without decimals, use `integer` or `bigint`. A typical use of `decimal` as a column type would be a "product price" column or an "interest rate". A typical use of an integer type would be e.g. a column that stores how *many* products were ordered (assuming you can't order "half" a product).

`double` and `real` are also types that can store decimal values, but they are **approximate** types. This means you don't necessarily retrieve the value you stored. For details please see: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: The phrase 'there is no difference' is neither a quote from the manual nor from your answer.  'decimal and numeric are equivalent' is a quote from both, but the OP was aware of that and asked for the difference, which the other answers addressed.

Answer (score 68):

Quoted straight from https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20211.1325269672@sss.pgh.pa.us

> There isn't any difference, in Postgres.  There are two type names
>   because the SQL standard requires us to accept both names.  In a quick
>   look in the standard it appears that the only difference is this:
>
> ```
>      17)NUMERIC specifies the data type exact numeric, with the decimal
>         precision and scale specified by the <precision> and <scale>.
>
>      18)DECIMAL specifies the data type exact numeric, with the decimal
>         scale specified by the <scale> and the implementation-defined
>         decimal precision equal to or greater than the value of the
>         specified <precision>.
> ```
>
> ie, for DECIMAL the implementation is allowed to allow more digits
>   than requested to the left of the decimal point.  Postgres doesn't
>   exercise that freedom so there's no difference between these types for
>   us.
>
> ```
>       regards, tom lane
> ```

Answer (score 25):

They are the synonym of each other and functionally same. The [SQL:2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003#Documentation_availability) standard says:

```
21) NUMERIC specifies the data type
    exact numeric, with the decimal
    precision and scale specified by the
    <precision> and <scale>.

22) DECIMAL specifies the data type
    exact numeric, with the decimal scale
    specified by the <scale> and the
    implementation-defined decimal
    precision equal to or greater than the
    value of the specified <precision>.
```