# Postgres - insert NUMERIC[] value '0' in lower UNION select statement

Tags: postgresql, types, numeric

In POSTGRES - I am trying to create a view from 2 tables.  When the value of '0' is coded for insertion as a value for the EAST_LONGITUDE_NMBR column of datatype NUMERIC[24,20] in the lower portion of a UNION select statement, an ERROR Message is generated.

The view EXTENTS' column EAST_LONGITUDE_NMBR comes from the table and column, CELL_EXTENT.EAST_LONGITUDE_NMBR with a datatype of NUMERIC[24,20]

The following is the code.

```
    CREATE VIEW EXTENTS
    (
       ID,
       EXTENT_TYPE,
       NAME,
       EAST_LONGITUDE_NMBR
    )

    AS
       SELECT 
          "CELL_EXTENT"."CELL_ID_NMBR",
          'CELL',
          UPPER ("CELL_EXTENT"."CELL_NAME"), 
          "CELL_EXTENT"."EAST_LONGITUDE_NMBR"
       FROM "EARTH"."CELL_EXTENT"

   UNION
       (SELECT 
           "AREA_INTEREST"."AREA_ID_NMBR",
           'GEOPOLITICAL',
           UPPER ("AREA_INTEREST"."AREA_NAME"),
           0
       FROM "EARTH"."AREA_INTEREST");
```

The inserted value '0' in the lower UNION select causes the following error in the creation of view EXTENTS.

ERROR:  UNION types numeric[] and integer cannot be matched

I have tried the following and received the errors shown:

```
    0                 ERROR:  UNION types numeric[] and integer cannot be matched
    0.0               ERROR:  UNION types numeric[] and numeric cannot be matched
    0.0::NUMERIC[]    ERROR:  cannot cast type numeric to numeric[]
    0::NUMERIC[]      ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to numeric[]
```

I have checked numerous websites with discussions about the Postgres datatypes, particularly NUMERIC, NUMERIC[], INTEGER, DECIMAL

[Difference between DECIMAL and NUMERIC datatype in PSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730538/difference-between-decimal-and-numeric-datatype-in-psql)

https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/655

https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/mapping-oracle-datatypes-to-postgresql/

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-to_number/

I could go on, but you get the picture.  There is a lot about datatypes but there are no examples for '0' as an actual value in Postgres code for a column of datatype NUMERIC[] in a UNION statement.

I feel this is a simple fix, a couple of keystrokes here or there to set the value proper, but it eludes me.  I am using pgAdmin4.

Can you help?
Thanks,
Margaret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems easy: use an array instead of 0.

Depending on what you prefer, you could use

```
ARRAY[]::numeric[]   -- empty array
```

or

```
ARRAY[0]::numeric[]  -- array with a single 0
```