# Subtraction result is inaccurate when stored in a column with a datatype double in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, floating-point, double, laravel-5.8

I have this update query in laravel where I subracted a value to a **total_qty** column with a **double** datatype. Example: When **250** is **subtracted** by **15.1** the result should be **234.9** but in the **total_qty** with a double datatype column, it stored **234.4**. What is wrong with this?

Update Query

```
InventoryRecord::where('id', $dataSales[$i]['sales_inv_id'])
                ->update(['total_qty' => $dataSales[$i]['actual_inv_quantity']-$dataSales[$i]['sales_qty']]);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that the operands are actually 250 and 15.1? Floating point math has a level of imprecision, but not at this order of magnitude.

Comment: So what datatype should I use then if there are decimal points?

Comment: How should I perform this query to return an accurate result then?

Comment: Here's [something to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730538/difference-between-decimal-and-numeric-datatype-in-psql) regarding storage of decimals. But your problem must be elsewhere, I've never encountered floating point calculations that are .5 off. Have you dumped the variables to verify they actually contain what you think they do?

Comment: Is this the only value that is off? Per @El_Vanja I have to believe you are not working with the values you think you are.