# What is the type of 100.0 in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, default

I am trying to understand whether I would prefer to cast to NUMERIC or to DECIMAL in PostgreSQL. I have read that [they are basically functionally the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43624470/3347826). One factor which might affect my decision is the default type when a decimal number is manually written, e.g.

```
SELECT percentage, 100.0
FROM grades
```

So the question is:

**What type is 100.0 in the query above?**

I was unable to find the answer in previous questions. I only know how to find the type of a column in a database, not an individual number. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the literal value is `numeric` (or `decimal` which is the same thing).  This is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS).  However, the documentation is a little convoluted.  The decimal point makes this numeric.  Without a decimal point, it could be either `int` or `bigint`.

Postgres supports `numeric` without scale and precision, so these are actually `NULL`.

To answer this sort of question, I often do a simple test.  The following idea works in any database:

```
create table t as
    select 100.0 as x;

select * 
from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'x';
```

Or for a simpler Postgres-specific approach:

```
select pg_typeof(100.0)
```

As in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=87c3f049cb63cb0c313cf9573bcb192f).

Comment: Thank you for the help. After your answer I also tried your suggestion of `select pg_typeof(100.0)` and the output was `numeric`. I will accept your answer as soon as the 5-minute timer is complete.